# Circumventing the maximum number of segments limit

Tags: segments

It says in a [support thread](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/reefine/viewthread/12862#41769) that Expression Engine has a maximum number of segments allowed that can't be changed (I can't think of a reason why they would need to do so).

I can't change the directory structure of my resources since it is structured by a ready made template. So I am stuck.

Does someone have a solution circumvent the issue of having too many segments?

Or at least disable Expression Engine from capturing and interpreting that page since the the links that I have that go over the maximum limit point to CSS files which don't need EE interpretation.

Comment: The maximum number of segments is 9. Give us more details, please. Maybe we can find an alternative.

Comment: I'm unclear, are these files on the server and not requests that ExpressionEngine should be handling?

Comment: @sobral The segments that I have is 10

Comment: @Derek The files are on the server. They are just simple CSS files that don't need EE processing.

Comment: See Johnathan Waters answer below then, it sounds like you have a server config issue. ExpressionEngine is not involved in files served outside the application. If his answer does not help, I suggest editing your question to include your .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

If you have structured you htaccess like the [htaccess example](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html). ExpressionEngine will not be consulted when accessing folders or files on your server.

These two lines in the htaccess are important

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

These make sure that if you are accessing a folder or file (like your css files), then do not have ExpressionEngine parse it. This essentially means there is no limit to your segments.